# Python subprocess nmap output different from terminal command

Tags: python, subprocess, output, nmap

I'm trying to use the output of nmap command in linux (shell output):

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
------
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.98
Host is up (0.094s latency).
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:CE:0A:9F (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
```

In a python script via subprocess:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["nmap", "-sn", "192.168.1.0/24"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print ("*** Running nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24 ***\n", output)
```

Which works pretty well except from the fact that I NEED the MAC line that shell output has and subprocess doesn't.

subprocess output:

```
\nNmap scan report for 192.168.1.98\nHost is up (0.015s latency).\n
```

I'm working on an idea of getting IP via MAC/Name and I can't see how to do it without that line...

Comment: Are you running the script as root?

Comment: I don't think it's writing to stderr. Have you tried prefixing with sudo? Although, using a package is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks @CMinusMinus! That solved it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run nmap as a subprocess in python, You can just install the nmap library and import it.

```
pip install python-nmap
```

Then write your code:

```
import json
import nmap

np = nmap.PortScanner()

target = '192.168.1.0/24'

# Scan the subnet 
results = np.scan(hosts=target, arguments='-sn')

# Clean the data nmap returns
results = results['scan']
output = {}
for result in results:
    output[result] = {}
    # Add the MAC addr to the IP
    try:
        output[result]['mac']       = results[result]['addresses']['mac']
    except:
        output[result]['mac']       = 'No MAC address avalible'
    # Add the vendor to the IP
    try:
        output[result]['vendor']    = list(results[result]['vendor'].values())[0]
    except:
        output[result]['vendor']    = 'No vendor info avalible'

print(json.dumps(output,indent=2))
```

When you run your code you have to run it as sudo or else you wont get the MAC addresses.

Output should look like this

```
{
  "192.168.1.1": {
    "mac": "16:91:82:xx:xx:xx",
    "vendor": "No vendor info avalible"
  },
  "192.168.1.10": {
    "mac": "44:39:C4:xx:xx:xx",
    "vendor": "Universal Global Scientific Industrial"
  },
  "192.168.1.50": {
    "mac": "No MAC address avalible",
    "vendor": "No vendor info avalible"
  }
}
```

I hope it was helpful :-)

Comment: Thanks @Mama. I was messing around with "python-nmap" version but it didn't solve my problem (Or I didn't figure how to solve it). I've used this version with this method `nmap = nmap3.NmapHostDiscovery()
results = nmap.nmap_no_portscan("192.168.1.0/24")` The output works, but it does not gives me MAC addres or names, just IP and status.

Comment: This is the output:`{'state': 'up', 'reason': 'conn-refused', 'reason_ttl': '0', 'addr': '192.168.1.98', 'addrtype': 'ipv4'}` I need MAC and name in order to see IP Owners... maybe it's about conn-refused?

Comment: If I run my script as "sudo" I get this error: `[sudo] password for daniziz: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nmap_rb.py", line 2, in <module>
    import nmap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nmap'`

Comment: Ok, I've done it with `sudo pip install python-nmap` since if I don't install it with sudo privileges I cant run .py script with sudo. Im going to play with JSON format in order to get my vendors, but this is better way than subprocess option.

Comment: Here is my solution: `for result in results:
        try:
            # View to list and append  
            vendor = list(results[result]["vendor"].values())[0]
            vendors_check.append(vendor)
        except IndexError as E:
            print("Element scan error, not adding to list and continuing...")`

Comment: Ive added your solution :-)